# Interface defines non async version but implementation needs to call an async method which results in interface does not implement error

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a simple interface:

```
public interface IValidation
{
    string Validate();
}
```

One of the implementations requires a dependency which has an async method and i get compilation errors: `The await operator can only be used within an async method`

```
public class Foo : IValidation
{
    private IAuthorizationService _authorizationSvc { get; }

    public Foo(IAuthorizationService authorizationSvc)
    {
        _authorizationSvc = authorizationSvc;
    }

    public string Validate()
    {
        var result = await _authorizationSvc.ValidateAuthorizationAsync(validationParams);
    }
}
```

When i change the implementation like this, i get a different error: "`Foo does not implement interface member 'IValidation.Validate'`"

```
public class Foo : IValidation
{
    private IAuthorizationService _authorizationSvc { get; }

    public Foo(IAuthorizationService authorizationSvc)
    {
        _authorizationSvc = authorizationSvc;
    }

    public async Task<string> Validate()
    {
        var result = await _authorizationSvc.ValidateAuthorizationAsync(validationParams);
    }
}
```

Kindly provide how to fix this!

thanks!

Comment: "How to fix this", there's not just one way to "fix" this. Basically, in order to call an async method from a sync method you have to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, and hope this won't deadlock, or you will have to make the method that wants to await async as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Ideally* I suspect you'd update the interface:

```
public interface IValidation
{
    Task<string> Validate();
}
```

Because if this operation is (or even *could be*) asynchronous then the consuming code needs to know that.

This certainly solves the issue of the implementation which has an async operation, but what about the rest of the implementations?  They don't necessarily have to be `async`, they just need to return a `Task<string>`.  Which can be done with:

```
return Task.FromResult(someString);
```

Comment: "For consistency they'd also have async methods" do they? Methods don't need to be async to return a `Task<string>`

Comment: @Joelius: Fair point.  I suppose as an alternative to `await Task.Yield()` they might otherwise use something like `return Task.FromResult(someValue)`.

Comment: Yea, which would be more ideal because you can avoid the internal state machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, at your own risk, something like this:

```
public async Task<string> Validate()
{
    var capturedSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    try
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

        var result = _authorizationSvc
            .ValidateAuthorizationAsync(validationParams)
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    finally
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedSynchronizationContext);
    }
}
```

You need to evaluate very carefully if this has no impacts on your system.